# pandas keep row if it contains part of string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a string as `String = 'Oil - this company`

In my dataframe df1:

```
id   CompanyName 
1    Oil - this company
2    oil
3    oily
4    comp
```

I want to keep the rows that contain part of CompanyName

My final df should be: df1

```
id   CompanyName 
1    Oil - this company
2    oil
```

I tried:

```
df = df[df['CompanyName'].str.contains(String)]
```

but it deleted the second row 2  oil

Is there any way to keep the company Name that contains part of the string?

Comment: what about a company name of just `this` or just `company`?

Comment: Why do you expect the string `'oil'` to contain the string `'Oil - this company'`?

Comment: @HenryYik I tried the following:

try:
        company_part = string.split("•")[0].rstrip()
    except:
        raise
    
    try:
        company_part = string.split(" - ")[0].rstrip()
    
    except:
        raise

To get the part before ("  -  ") but it didnt change the name